# Get grep context with multiline regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Do grep's -Pz and -C options work together? I'm trying to match an adjacent-lines phrase and print it's context. The extended regex and context options work separately, but not together like this (prints the whole file):

```
grep -C 2 -Pz ".*word.*\n.*phrase.*" file.txt
```

content of file.txt:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
word ...other text
phrase ...yet another text
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

expected result:

```
line 4
line 5
word ...other text
phrase ...yet another text
line 6
line 7
```

Comment: provide sample input from file.txt

Comment: provided text file

Comment: it seems it works, what's your expected result?

Comment: I've updated the question. Try it with a lower -c param.

Comment: Are your lines null terminated? You have `-z` so your 'lines' must be terminated by `\0`

Comment: No, they aren't. But that could be the reason why it prints the whole file - it treats it as a single line.

Comment: `The extended regex and context options work separately` - OP is clearly asking for regex help so restoring `regex` tag back.

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot. It is not allowed. `-Pz` and `-C` do not like each other. Fear not, There is a way to do what you want to do:

```sh
grep -Pzo ".*\n.*\n.*.*word.*\n.*phrase.*\n.*\n.*" file.txt
```

Or you could parameterize it

```sh
BEFORE=2
AFTER=2
grep -Pzo "(.*\n){$BEFORE}.*word.*\n.*phrase.*(\n.*){$AFTER}" file.txt
```

1. You use `-Pzo` do only print out lines that match your specified pattern.
2. Include some number of `.*\n.*`'s padding your pattern string.

You may find this bash function useful:

```sh
function pad_grep()(
        usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-ABC] [EXPR] [FILE]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

        A=0
        B=0
        while getopts "A:B:C:" flag; do
                case "$flag" in
                        A) A=$OPTARG;;
                        B) B=$OPTARG;;
                        C) A=$OPTARG;B=$OPTARG;;
                        *) usage;;
                esac
        done
        EXPR=${@:$OPTIND:1}
        FILE=${@:$OPTIND+1:1}

        # Error checking
        [ ${#EXPR} -eq 0 ] && usage
        [[ ${#FILE} -ne 0 && ! -f ${FILE} ]] && usage

        grep -Pzo "(.*\n){$B}${EXPR}(\n.*){$A}" $FILE
)

# Do it yourself
grep -Pzo ".*\n.*\n.*\n.*.*word.*\n.*phrase.*\n.*\n.*" file.txt

# Use the function
pad_grep -B 3 -A 2 '.*word.*\n.*phrase.*' file.txt
pad_grep -C 2 '.*word.*\n.*phrase.*' file.txt
```

Comment: This is great for small files, but I got a 'grep: memory exhausted' error on my real file :)

Comment: I believe that issue is grounds for a new question. According to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90036/grep-memory-exhausted) some valid solutions to your memory issue might be to add the `--mmap` option, or try using `truncate`

Answer (score 2):

Likely your issue is the `z` flag to GNU grep which then changes of the definition of a line to terminated by a `\0`

Easy to demo. Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
word ...other text
phrase ...yet another text
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$txt"  | ggrep --context=2  -Pz "word|phrase"
# prints all the lines
```

Or:

```
$ echo "$txt"  | ggrep --context=2  -P "word|phrase"
line 4
line 5
word ...other text
phrase ...yet another text
line 6
line 7
```

Which you can demonstrate will work with `z` by actually have NUL terminations for the lines:

```
$ echo "$txt" | tr '\n' '\0' | ggrep --context=2  -Pz "word|phrase" | tr '\0' '\n'
line 4
line 5
word ...other text
phrase ...yet another text
line 6
line 7
```

---

For perl regex's and logic of before and after and multilines, you might as well just use **Perl**!

Given:

```
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
word ...other text
betweener 1, line 7
betweener 2, line 8
phrase ...yet another text
line 10
line 11
line 12
line 13
line 14
```

You can do:

```
# $b=2 is equivalent to grep -B 2, or lines before
# $a=2 is equivalent to grep -A 2, or lines after
$ perl -lne 'BEGIN{$b=2; $a=2;}
             print join("\n", @a) if (/word/);
             print if (/word/../phrase/) || ($c && $c--);
             $c=$b if (/phrase/);
             shift @a if push(@a, $_)>$a;' file
```

Or, you can use POSIX or GNU awk as well:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{b=2; a=2}
   /word/ { for (i=FNR-b;i<=FNR-1;i++) 
                 print arr[i]   # print the lines before the first match
            f=1}                # flag we are in the match
    f || (c && c--)             # print either if in the match or tail context
    /phrase/ {f=0; c=a}          # end match, start tail
    {for (ln in arr) 
         if (ln<FNR-b) delete arr[ln] # rolling line buffer
    arr[FNR]=$0}                # save current line
' file
```

Either prints:

```
line 4
line 5
word ...other text
betweener 1, line 7
betweener 2, line 8
phrase ...yet another text
line 10
line 11
```

That works even with no 'betweener' lines.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ggrep but thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: `ggrep` is just GNU grep on *my* system (Mac OS / BSD). If you are on Linux -- it is *your* grep too!

Comment: Then I think the regex needs to be changed. If I'm not mistaken, the pipe in regex means "or" and that's not what I need, because it picks up any of the keywords (I need consecutive lines). I have trouble putting the \0 into regex: none of (\0, \x0, \x00) work.

Comment: I was just using `"word|phrase"` to demo that `z` does not work with `\n` terminated lines. For an actual regex that DOES work -- that is likely a new question.

Comment: @OndrejSotolar: I updated with a Perl that should work for you.